# Telegram Bot: Sending an image only once, not downloading it the next time

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I'm using the telebotframework to run my Telegram bots with Node.JS.
I am making some sort of game where pictures are also sent. Is it possible to send a picture only once or not at all? Because my picture album is now filled with duplicate pictures.
I tried using a fileID link instead but it still seems to fill the image gallery and the fileIDs don;t seem to be permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incoming `file_id`s are [permanent](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#can-i-count-on-file-ids-to-be-persistent).

You can exploit that by just sending your bot the file you want the bot to send once and using the `file_id` over and over again. With that trick your bot can even send files larger than 50 MB.

But I cannot reproduce your problem with the filled image album.

Comment: My image album is filled with random birds as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/siFpY9z.jpg

Even though I use the ```file_id``` every time.

Comment: I found a "Save to Gallery" option in Telegram settings. I have turned it off, so that's maybe why I could not reproduce your problem with the filled gallery.

Comment: Yes I've found that option too in the past 2 years haha. Thanks for your reply though!